# Django: When to use UUID?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I know this question is the one someone already asked but I really don't understand when I should use UUID.
I just started to try to bulid REST API in Django. And I've read we should use UUID but I don't understand how to use it.

For example, I currently use `id` to refer to a specific object in api views as I write in usual `views.py`. Is it what I should not do? If so, how users can refer to a object using `UUID`? When is it used?

```
@api_view(['GET', 'PUT', 'DELETE'])
def specific_entry(request, pk, format=None):
    entry = get_object_or_404(Entry, id=pk)
    ...
```

Comment: You said, "... I've read we should use UUID". Where did you read this? Can you post a link to where you read this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's up to you. UUID is such complex and unique, not auto incremented field that is used instead of common Id field. So if you want to use it you can just specify in your model:

```
import uuid

id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, primary_key=true)
```

But it's up to you, you can continue using AutoField for id.

In order to compare you can read [there](https://medium.com/@Mareks_082/auto-increment-keys-vs-uuid-a74d81f7476a)

Comment: How can users refer to the object? Like currently I can jump into the url like `api/entry/1` but if I use UUID as the url instead of pk, how can I refer to the page?

Comment: No, all id will be uuid `32aeecaa-8e05-4624-a149-d3ef1fb9ecc3`, so now url path will look like: `api/entry/32aeecaa-8e05-4624-a149-d3ef1fb9ecc3`

Comment: How can the users refer to any `id`?  How would a user know to use `api/entry/1`? A lucky guess?

Comment: Yes, no way to guess, the probability is to low. So if you need user to know their id it's better to do as you did: use auto incremented id.

Comment: Thanks. I got it.